# Alloy predicate for a tree

Tags: alloy

I am trying to write a predicate in alloy which will determine if a set of nodes is a tree. I have the pseudo code, but am confused on how to implement it. I am new to alloy so thank you to all of those who respond in advance.

```
sig Node[]

pred isTree [r: Node -> Node] {
// Every node reachable from root
// No cycles
// No node has more than 1 more parent.
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `graph` module? They have an implementation of trees there.

Comment: @Hovercouch I have not, as I am trying to construct it from scratch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out this [online Alloy tutorial](http://alloytools.org/tutorials/online/frame-FS-1.html) in which a fileSystem is modeled.
It's also a tree structure, so you pretty much have your answers.

More specific answers require more specific questions and a display of your attempts.

We're not giving away solutions to homeworks ;-).